# Sitecore admin SSL implementation

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to implement SSL on SItecore Admin login page, Could you please tell me how to implement the SSL only on Admin page other than the whole site. I cant use wildcard since the structure is diferent for sitecore login

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend going down this route without some additional restrictions. Although it will be possible to secure part of the site with SLL as patrickmjones has suggested, it is not recommended practice to have mixed mode within a single site due to potentially having sessions hijacked. If you haven't already then read 
["Breaking the Web's Cookie Jar"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/11/breaking-the-webs-cookie-jar.html) and his recommendation that ["Should All Web Traffic Be Encrypted?"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/should-all-web-traffic-be-encrypted.html). Troy Hunt's [5 ways to implement HTTPS in an insufficient manner (and leak sensitive data)](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/04/5-ways-to-implement-https-in.html) is a great read that gives some good insight into the little nuances. So particularly in this instance, if someone hijacked your session they have full access to your Sitecore admin session with the potential to wreak havoc on your websites.

Instead, if you require your admin section to be secure then I would recommend one of the following:

1. A truly separate CMS server, which sits within your firewall and only accessible from within your network
2. Users should only be allowed access to the server via VPN connection
3. Place IP restrictions in IIS to only allow specific range of IP addresses access to the /sitecore folders

Additionally adding the SSL encryption will not be an issue, but don't rely on it for the only form of protection. Personally I would try to avoid making the CMS server publicly available  if at all possible.

Comment: Yes, I like this approach much better.  Hadn't read "Should All Web Traffic Be Encrypted?"... nice articles.

Comment: hi jammy, how about creating sub domain , implement wild card certificate on it and redirect that to admin url ??

Comment: however you do it, SSL on it's own is not sufficient, you still need to restrict access to the admin section IMO

Comment: Hi Jammy, if we have implemented ip restrictions on cms and wild card encryption by creating a subdomain and redirecting it to login page. how would i address the issue to restrict  when any one who knows the cms login naming convention tries to access via http???

Comment: Add in the restrictions that Patrick has suggested. You could probably force redirect to https but would need to investigate best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I can not speak to whether this is recommended, but it seems like a nice idea so +1 for that.

I was able to achieve this in my test bed by adding the "port" value of 443 to each of the following sites in the Web.config.

```
<site name="shell" port="443" virtualFolder="/sitecore/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/login" content="master" contentStartItem="/Home" enableWorkflow="true" enableAnalytics="false" analyticsDefinitions="content" xmlControlPage="/sitecore/shell/default.aspx" browserTitle="Sitecore" htmlCacheSize="2MB" registryCacheSize="3MB" viewStateCacheSize="200KB" xslCacheSize="5MB"/>
<site name="login" port="443" virtualFolder="/sitecore/login" physicalFolder="/sitecore/login" enableAnalytics="false" database="core" domain="sitecore" disableXmlControls="true"/>
```

The second part, and non-Sitecore part, is to make sure you have a valid Server certificate installed in IIS and to have the correct binding set to your site in IIS to use that certificate.

Once that's done you simply navigate to https://mysite.com/sitecore to access the backend and that http://mysite.com/sitecore does not work.  If you want something more fancy like a redirect that is up to you.